# WP_Query is getting the post but the_post() not rendering any Post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, templates

Problem Description:

the code below is from a single-featured-article.php file . Copying this custom template for a custom post type 'featured-article' from my plug-in to the active theme folder . The template is rendering fine . Even the query showing data in the array .

see: result of print_r($featured_articles) is in the second part

But 'the_post()' not showing any post. What's wrong with code ?

```
<?php

$featured_articles = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'featured-article'));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($featured_articles);
echo '</pre>';

if ($featured_articles->have_posts()):
    while ($featured_articles->have_posts()) : $featured_articles->the_post();

        // Include the single post content template.
        get_template_part('template-parts/post/content', get_post_format());

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) {
            comments_template();
        }

        if (is_singular('attachment')) {
            // Parent post navigation.
            the_post_navigation(array(
                'prev_text' => _x('<span class="meta-nav">Published in</span><span class="post-title">%title</span>', 'Parent post link', 'twentysixteen'),
            ));
        } elseif (is_singular('featured-article')) {
            // Previous/next post navigation.
            the_post_navigation(array(
                'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __('Next', 'twentysixteen') . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __('Next post:', 'twentysixteen') . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __('Previous', 'twentysixteen') . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __('Previous post:', 'twentysixteen') . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
            ));
        }

        // End of the loop.
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

result of print_r($featured_articles) :

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => featured-article
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => featured-article
            [error] => 
            [m] => 
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] => 
            [attachment] => 
            [attachment_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [static] => 
            [pagename] => 
            [page_id] => 0
            [second] => 
            [minute] => 
            [hour] => 
            [day] => 0
            [monthnum] => 0
            [year] => 0
            [w] => 0
            [category_name] => 
            [tag] => 
            [cat] => 
            [tag_id] => 
            [author] => 
            [author_name] => 
            [feed] => 
            [tb] => 
            [paged] => 0
            [meta_key] => 
            [meta_value] => 
            [preview] => 
            [s] => 
            [sentence] => 
            [title] => 
            [fields] => 
            [menu_order] => 
            [embed] => 
            [category__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_name__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_parent__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_parent__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [author__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [author__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
            [suppress_filters] => 
            [cache_results] => 1
            [update_post_term_cache] => 1
            [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
            [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
            [posts_per_page] => 2
            [nopaging] => 
            [comments_per_page] => 50
            [no_found_rows] => 
            [order] => DESC
        )

    [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => AND
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [queried_terms] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_table] => wp_posts
            [primary_id_column] => ID
        )

    [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => 
            [meta_table] => 
            [meta_id_column] => 
            [primary_table] => 
            [primary_id_column] => 
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [clauses:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [has_or_relation:protected] => 
        )

    [date_query] => 
    [request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'featured-article' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 2
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 433
                    [post_author] => 1
                    [post_date] => 2017-09-16 19:13:24
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2017-09-16 13:13:24
                    [post_content] => dsfsf fsf werfwe frewgtv r j tut ttyuytu u tyu
                    [post_title] => DCV featured article
                    [post_excerpt] => 
                    [post_status] => publish
                    [comment_status] => closed
                    [ping_status] => closed
                    [post_password] => 
                    [post_name] => dcv-featured-article
                    [to_ping] => 
                    [pinged] => 
                    [post_modified] => 2017-09-16 19:13:24
                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-09-16 13:13:24
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [guid] => http://rs-wordpress.com/?post_type=featured-article&p=433
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => featured-article
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [1] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 432
                    [post_author] => 1
                    [post_date] => 2017-09-16 18:49:05
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2017-09-16 12:49:05
                    [post_content] => chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon chloro-fluro carbon
                    [post_title] => cfc feature article
                    [post_excerpt] => 
                    [post_status] => publish
                    [comment_status] => closed
                    [ping_status] => closed
                    [post_password] => 
                    [post_name] => cfc-feature-article
                    [to_ping] => 
                    [pinged] => 
                    [post_modified] => 2017-09-16 18:49:05
                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-09-16 12:49:05
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [guid] => http://rs-wordpress.com/?post_type=featured-article&p=432
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => featured-article
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

        )

    [post_count] => 2
    [current_post] => -1
    [in_the_loop] => 
    [post] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 433
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2017-09-16 19:13:24
            [post_date_gmt] => 2017-09-16 13:13:24
            [post_content] => dsfsf fsf werfwe frewgtv r j tut ttyuytu u tyu
            [post_title] => DCV featured article
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => dcv-featured-article
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2017-09-16 19:13:24
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-09-16 13:13:24
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://rs-wordpress.com/?post_type=featured-article&p=433
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => featured-article
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [comment_count] => 0
    [current_comment] => -1
    [found_posts] => 3
    [max_num_pages] => 2
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 
    [is_archive] => 1
    [is_date] => 
    [is_year] => 
    [is_month] => 
    [is_day] => 
    [is_time] => 
    [is_author] => 
    [is_category] => 
    [is_tag] => 
    [is_tax] => 
    [is_search] => 
    [is_feed] => 
    [is_comment_feed] => 
    [is_trackback] => 
    [is_home] => 
    [is_404] => 
    [is_embed] => 
    [is_paged] => 
    [is_admin] => 
    [is_attachment] => 
    [is_singular] => 
    [is_robots] => 
    [is_posts_page] => 
    [is_post_type_archive] => 1
    [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => 8c6cb592fd6eb096f5db534a95e5b42c
    [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
    [thumbnails_cached] => 
    [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
    [compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => query_vars_hash
            [1] => query_vars_changed
        )

    [compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => init_query_flags
            [1] => parse_tax_query
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in the syntax:

`if ($featured_articles > have_posts()):
    while ($featured_articles > have_posts()) : $featured_articles->the_post();`

in the `if` and `while` conditions should be `->` instead `>`.

Answer (score 2):

`the_post()` doesn't render anything. Read [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/the_post/):

> Retrieves the next post, sets up the post, sets the ‘in the loop’
>   property to true.

So all it does is set it so that functions like `the_title()` or `the_content()` use the title and content from the current post in the query as you loop through it.

If a post isn't rendering it would be because `get_template_part('template-parts/post/content', get_post_format());` is referring to a template doesn't exist. You need to make sure that template exists and uses the right functions, like `the_title()`, to output content. `the_post()` doesn't output anything.

EDIT: Or, more likely, it's this:

```
$featured_articles > have_posts()
```

That's not the correct syntax. `have_posts()` is a method on `$featured_articles` so it needs to be written like this:

```
$featured_articles->have_posts()
```